# Operations with tag select in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

How about, I try to perform a simple operation (addition, subtraction or multiplication).
99 + 5 = 104
Form

```
<select> + <input> = result
```

Between input tags, there is no problem, the problem is when I have a list of numbers to select from the BD.

In the BD the following data are available. As you can see, the discounts do not match your ID.

```
Id discount
1   100
2   99
3   98
4   96
5   95
```

If I want to perform an operation, at the time of listing the discounts, the label

```
<option value = "<? PHP echo ''. $ row ['id'];?>"> <? PHP echo ''. $ row ['discount'];?> </ option>
```

The operation is done with the id and not with the discount.
An example of a sum, we select the discount with 99, then insert the amount of 5 the correct result = 104.

The problem is that at the time of the operation instead of 99 it takes the value of its ID = 2, consequently 2 + 5 = 7.

My question at the time of performing the operation as I can take the discount value instead of Id.

```
<html>
<head>
<script language='javascript'>
function fadd(){
 n1=document.f1.cveDiscount.value;
 n2=document.f1.amount.value;
res=document.f1.resul.value;
res=parseInt(n1)+parseInt(n2);
document.f1.resul.value=res;

}
</script>
</head>
<body>
  <form name='f1' action="" method=POST>
  <label name=lblnum1>Num 1:</label>
  <select name="cveDiscount" class="form-control ">
    <?PHP

    if ($resultado = $mysqli->query("SELECT id,discount FROM discount  order by id desc", MYSQLI_USE_RESULT)) {

      while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($resultado)){
        ?>
        <tr>
          <option value="<?PHP echo ''.$row['id'];?>"><?PHP echo ''.$row['discount'];?></option>
        </tr>
        <?PHP
      }
    }
    ?>
    <option value="#" selected>Select discount</option>
  </select>

  <label name=lblnum2>Num 2:</label>
  <input type=text name='amount'/>

  <input type=button value="   =   " onclick="fadd()">

  <input type=text name='resul'/>

</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Just retrieve `discount` from query and put it as `value` in your `option` tag. Currently it is passing `id` as `value` and you dont need `id` to show in UI

Comment: Note you are developing a bad habit of creating global variables rather than declaring them local using `var, let or const`. Can run into weird bugs that are hard to trace by doing that if you use same variable names eleswhere

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing your javascript a bit will also let you use the text from the select tag options, if you need to keep those id values in there for whatever reason:

```
var sel = document.f1.cveDiscount;
var n1 = sel.options[sel.selectedIndex].text;
```

This will return the expected results.

Answer (score 2):

You can use:

> [selectedOptions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLSelectElement/selectedOptions): ...contains a list of the  elements contained within the  element that are currently selected. The list of selected options is an HTMLCollection object with one entry per currently selected option.

Hence, you can change from:

```
n1=document.f1.cveDiscount.value;
```

to:

```
n1 = document.f1.cveDiscount.selectedOptions[0].textContent;
```

In any case I'd suggest to use [.addEventListener()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) at dom ready instead to inline event handler.

The snippet:

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(e) {
   document.querySelector('[type=button]').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
        n1 = document.f1.cveDiscount.selectedOptions[0].textContent;
        n2 = document.f1.amount.value;
        res = document.f1.resul.value;
        res = parseInt(n1) + parseInt(n2);
        document.f1.resul.value = res;
    })
})
```

```html
<form name='f1' action="" method=POST>
    <label name=lblnum1>Num 1:</label>
    <select name="cveDiscount" class="form-control ">
        <option value="1">100</option>
        <option value="2">99</option>
        <option value="3">98</option>
        <option value="4">96</option>
        <option value="5">95</option>
        <option value="#" selected>Select discount</option>
    </select>
    <label name=lblnum2>Num 2:</label>
    <input type=text name='amount'/>
    <input type=button value="   =   ">
    <input type=text name='resul'/>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just change value inside `option` with `discount`

```
<option value="<?PHP echo ''.$row['discount'];?>"><?PHP echo ''.$row['discount'];?></option>
```

In this way you can easly pass the `discount` as value instead of its `id`

Answer (score 1):

Currently you're showing the value of `Discount` in UI but you're actually passing `id` as the value for the addition.
Just retrieve discount from query and put it as value in your option tag as follows:

```
<select name="cveDiscount" class="form-control ">
    <?PHP

    if ($resultado = $mysqli->query("SELECT discount FROM discount  order by id desc", MYSQLI_USE_RESULT)) {

      while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($resultado)){
        ?>
        <tr>
          <option value="<?PHP echo ''.$row['discount'];?>"><?PHP echo ''.$row['discount'];?></option>
        </tr>
        <?PHP
      }
    }
    ?>
    <option value="#" selected>Select discount</option>
  </select>
```